# Check if two array's values are equal and in same order

Tags: java, lua

I'm stuck on a particular logic. I have two arrays and I need to check if those two arrays' values are equal and in same order. Looping is also allowed. Let's say:

```
array1 = {4, 3, 2, 1}
array2 = {1, 4, 3, 2} -- true. 

array1 = {4, 3, 2, 1}
array2 = {2, 1, 4, 3} -- true.
```

Duplicates are allowed in array values. I cannot sort the arrays as duplicates are allowed and it'll mess up the array order.

Comment: Iterate the array and check the values

Comment: Java or Lua? Make your choice already.

Comment: So you need to see if the values are in the same order, but they can start at any point in the array and wrap-around?

Comment: @DanArmstrong. Exactly.

Comment: Why is this even tagged Lua?

Comment: @warspyking - Because OP used Lua syntax in the examples.

Comment: @egor Okay - but why?

Comment: @warspyking - Because Lua is damn good.

Comment: @egor Can't argue with that logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your nested loops, but let's think a bit differently.  If we append the second array to itself, we could just do a "indexOf" operation of the first array on the second.  Here's a bit of untested code showing the idea:

```
public static boolean arraysMatch(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    int[] combined = new int[array2.length * 2];
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, combined, 0, array2.length);
    System.arraycopy(array2, 0, combined, array2.length, array2.length);
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(Arrays.asList(combined), Arrays.asList(array1)) != -1;
}
```

Or a more list-centric approach:

```
public static boolean arraysMatch(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    List<Integer> combined = new ArrayList<>(array2.length * 2);
    List<Integer> array2List = Arrays.asList(array2);
    combined.addAll(array2List);
    combined.addAll(array2List);
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(combined, Arrays.asList(array1)) != -1;
}
```

You can do looping and not copy data around, but it's a matter of programmer time vs. CPU time.

Edit: I know answer accepted, but it's still not really complete.  If allowed to use Apache Commons Lang: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html

```
public static boolean arraysMatch(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    return Collections.indexOfSubList(
        Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(ArrayUtils.addAll(array2, array2))),
        Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array1))
    ) != -1;
}
```

Comment: Creative; nice balance between code clarity and performance. At least in Java 8 `Arrays.asList()` does not accept an `int` array.

Comment: Looks like might need to manually populate List<Integer> sadly, since Java doesn't seem to have any direct array operations and we need to use the Collections class for indexOfSubList.

Comment: If O.P. is allowed to use Commons Lang: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/  ArrayUtils.toObject can bridge the gap: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28int[]%29

Comment: Final point: I didn't check the array lengths, which one might need to do depending on requirements.  Would want to make sure the lengths match.  This dead horse is well beaten.  Signing off.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**Code:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArrayComparison {

    //  Create arrays
    private static int[] array1 = new int[] {2,3,4,7,1};
    private static int[] array2 = new int[] {2,3,4,7,1};
    private static int[] array3 = new int[] {1,7,4,2,3};
    private static int[] array4 = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    private static int[] array5 = new int[] {2,3,4,5,1};

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(compareArrays(array1, array2));  // True
        System.out.println(compareArrays(array1, array3));  // True
        System.out.println(compareArrays(array1, array4));  // False
        System.out.println(compareArrays(array1, array5));  // False
    }

    /**
     * Compares if a1 is equal than a2, no matter the order
     * @param a1 Array 1
     * @param a2 Array 2
     * @return True if a1 == a2, false if a1 != a2. no matter the order
     */
    private static boolean compareArrays(int[] a1, int[] a2){
        boolean areEqual=false;
        //  Clone
        int[] a1Aux = a1.clone();
        int[] a2Aux = a2.clone();
        //  Sort
        Arrays.sort(a1Aux);
        Arrays.sort(a2Aux);
        //  Compare
        if(a1Aux.length == a2Aux.length){
            for(int i=0;i<a1Aux.length;i++){
                if(a1Aux[i] != a2Aux[i]){
                    return areEqual;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return areEqual;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: I doubt that it will return true for the two cases menitoned in the question. Maybe the OP will be able to stick in a nested loop to take those into account.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, code edited ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is straightforward (but very inefficient, involves a lot of copying). I stick with arrays of `int`s (no lists or other collections, no `Integer` objects).

```
public static boolean arraysWrappedEqual(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int array2startIndex = 0; array2startIndex < array2.length; array2startIndex++) {
        // compare beginning of array1 with end of array2 and vice versa
        int[] array1beginning = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, 0, array1.length - array2startIndex);
        int[] array1end = Arrays.copyOfRange(array1, array1.length - array2startIndex, array1.length);
        int[] array2beginning = Arrays.copyOfRange(array2, 0, array2startIndex);
        int[] array2end = Arrays.copyOfRange(array2, array2startIndex, array2.length);
        if (Arrays.equals(array1beginning, array2end) && Arrays.equals(array1end, array2beginning)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It returns true for both the cases in the question.